# input of type file in IE

Tags: javascript, file, input

Hello
I know in firefox and chrome exists .size to get file size with javascript and it's even possible to upload multifiles with ajax `(input type=file multiple=TRUE)` using `xmlhttp.send(file)` (or `xhr.sendAsBinary(file.files[0].getAsBinary());` in firefox<=3.5).
Now i am trying to make a sort of jquery plugin for multiple file uploader (of course using forms and frames  in IE detect) but will be much better if i could get file size in IE.
So is there any way to get file size  from input of type file in IE?

Answer (score -3):

You can use this for getting file size in IE:

`var fileSize = document.getElementById("somfile").size;`

Comment: it is not true. it is impossible in IE

Comment: I test it in IE9 and was ok. only must sure that there is one file selected in field

Comment: .size does not return the file size, I think it is the number of properties on the DOM object.